# Custom Post Types Archives and daily/monthly joke

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I have created a custom post type called joke using custom post types ui plugin. I have enabled archives for that ctp. I would like to have a page that would display the daily (or monthly) joke, and also have a page that would display an archive of all previous jokes. Is it possible, and if so, can you point as to how it can be achieved?

Comment: How do you want to choose the top daily/monthly joke?

To show all your jokes, you would be best to create a template for your CPT. See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display

Comment: for the daily joke I would choose the most recent joke published, that has a publish date of the current date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, following on from my comment above, I would suggest creating a template for your Jokes archive e.g. `archive-my_jokes.php` (where my_jokes is the name of your CPT). You can likely copy some template content from category.php or a similar existing template file to get started.
To deal with showing the top joke, you'll need to put your code before any loop in your template.
I'd suggest using `wp_get_recent_posts` (see [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts)) to call one post from your CPT.
For example:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post-type' => 'my_jokes', //CPT slug here
    );

$top_jokes = wp_get_recent_posts ($args);
     foreach ($top_jokes as $top_joke) {
        //Echo what you like here
        echo $top_joke['post_title'] . '<br />';
        echo $top_joke['post_content'];
    }
```

The styling of the above output is up to you to sort out according to your theme/template/styling needs.
N.B. The reason I used a foreach loop even though you only want one post is for flexibility later if you deicde you want more.